# Lower case "line" when referencing algorithmicx line with cleveref

Tags: cleveref, algpseudocode

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State\label{line} Hello World
\end{algorithmic}

This is a reference to \cref{line}.

\end{document}
```

The last line then reads: `This is a reference to Line 1`, but I would like it to be `This is a reference to line 1`. Of course, I could achieve this by removing the `capitalize` option, but I would like to keep things like theorems and algorithms capitalised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tell `cleveref` that “line” should be lowercase.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\crefname{line}{line}{lines}

\begin{document}

\section{Title}\label{sec}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State\label{line} Hello World
\end{algorithmic}

This is a reference to \cref{line}.

We're in~\cref{sec}.

\Cref{line}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That kind of works, but runs into trouble if you do want an uppercase "Line", e.g. at the beginning of a sentence.

Comment: @gTcV Updated...

Answer (score 0):

Either don't use the `capitalize` option or workaround:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\State\label{line} Hello World
\end{algorithmic}

This is a reference to \lcnamecref{line}~\ref{line}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made clear that I want to keep the `capitalize` option for all other references. And the workaround is a bit cumbersome...

Comment: @gTcV If you want capitalization for all other references, why not for the line? Making it lowercase seems very inconsistent then